# Javascript - Prevent right-click on scrollbar to see page source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Purpose is to prevent user from seeing web page source code by clicking right-click view page source. Also not to take any content copy paste.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('body')
    .attr('unselectable', 'on')
    .css('user-select', 'none')
    .on('selectstart dragstart', false);

//Disable cut copy paste
$('body').bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

//Disable mouse right click
$("body").on("contextmenu",function(e){
    return false;
});
});
```

I used this code and it works nice except for 2 cases:

1- The scrollbar. user can still right-click on it and choose view page source.

2- CTRL + U (chrome short cut to do the same job)

any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
CTRL + U Disabled by

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
        if (e.ctrlKey &&
            (e.keyCode === 67 ||
                e.keyCode === 86 ||
                e.keyCode === 85 ||
                e.keyCode === 117)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't stop people from seeing the browser source code. Even if you disable right click and ctrl+u, they will still be able to see it. In order for the browser to render it, the browser will have to receive the code and unless you can control the browser environment (like an entertainment kiosk), you'll be fighting a losing battle trying to stop people from seeing the source code.

For example, if you use chrome and hit f12, you'll be able to see it. Alternatively, if you use some sort of network packet sniffer, you'll be able to see it again.

Comment: I understand that. But we are trying to prevent as much as we can.

Comment: @MSaudi At what accessibility costs? People who really want to see your code will only be slowed by a matter of seconds, while many others will struggle to understand why their right-click menu fails or why nothing is selectable. Bottom line: it's not worth it in the long run.

Comment: Why would you do that? That's like a store patting down and doing extreme vetting on every customer that walks in and out of front door, while having side door unlocked and unwatched. It's pointless, silly and legitimate users will hate you. If something is sensitive, keep it serverside. If you want to protect content, copyright and sue for infringement if it gets out.

Comment: @gyre , thanks for your comment. You are right but it is a client requirement.

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && 
        (e.keyCode === 67 || 
         e.keyCode === 86 || 
         e.keyCode === 85 || 
         e.keyCode === 117)) {
        console.log('not allowed');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

};

to restrict ctrl+U.

Keycodes according to mozilla

```
CANCEL=     3
HELP=   6
BACK_SPACE=     8
TAB=    9
CLEAR=  12
RETURN=     13
ENTER=  14
SHIFT=  16
CONTROL=    17
ALT=    18
PAUSE=  19
CAPS_LOCK=  20
KANA=   21
HANGUL=     21
JUNJA=  23
FINAL=  24
HANJA=  25
KANJI=  25
ESCAPE=     27
CONVERT=    28
NONCONVERT=     29
ACCEPT=     30
MODECHANGE=     31
SPACE=  32
PAGE_UP=    33
PAGE_DOWN=  34
END=    35
HOME=   36
LEFT=   37
UP=     38
RIGHT=  39
DOWN=   40
SELECT=     41
PRINT=  42
EXECUTE=    43
PRINTSCREEN=    44
INSERT=     45
DELETE=     46
0=  48
1=  49
2=  50
3=  51
4=  52
5=  53
6=  54
7=  55
8=  56
9=  57
SEMICOLON=  59
EQUALS=     61
A=  65
B=  66
C=  67
D=  68
E=  69
F=  70
G=  71
H=  72
I=  73
J=  74
K=  75
L=  76
M=  77
N=  78
O=  79
P=  80
Q=  81
R=  82
S=  83
T=  84
U=  85
V=  86
W=  87
X=  88
Y=  89
Z=  90
CONTEXT_MENU=   93
SLEEP=  95
NUMPAD0=    96
NUMPAD1=    97
NUMPAD2=    98
NUMPAD3=    99
NUMPAD4=    100
NUMPAD5=    101
NUMPAD6=    102
NUMPAD7=    103
NUMPAD8=    104
NUMPAD9=    105
MULTIPLY=   106
ADD=    107
SEPARATOR=  108
SUBTRACT=   109
DECIMAL=    110
DIVIDE=     111
F1=     112
F2=     113
F3=     114
F4=     115
F5=     116
F6=     117
F7=     118
F8=     119
F9=     120
F10=    121
F11=    122
F12=    123
F13=    124
F14=    125
F15=    126
F16=    127
F17=    128
F18=    129
F19=    130
F20=    131
F21=    132
F22=    133
F23=    134
F24=    135
NUM_LOCK=   144
SCROLL_LOCK=    145
COMMA=  188
PERIOD=     190
SLASH=  191
BACK_QUOTE=     192
OPEN_BRACKET=   219
BACK_SLASH=     220
CLOSE_BRACKET=  221
QUOTE=  222
META=   224
```

Restrict Mouse right click on scrollbar try this following

```
var clickedOnScrollbar = function(mouseX)
{
   if( $(window).outerWidth() <= mouseX ){
        return true;   
    } 
    }

    $(document).mousedown(function(e){ 
    var isRightMB;
        e = e || window.event;

        if ("which" in e)  
            isRightMB = e.which == 3; 
        else if ("button" in e)  
            isRightMB = e.button == 2; 


        if(isRightMB){  
     if( clickedOnScrollbar(e.clientX) ){
        alert("Right click is not allowed"); 
      }
} 
    });
```